# Same internet time, but different time

Tags: windows, time, synchronization

I'm using a virtual server in U.S.A/Texas and its time is synchronized with "Time.windows.com". I too have in Canada/Quebec 3 PCs with a time synchronized with the same internet time. Unfortunately, my server in Texas is 40 seconds less than my 3 others PCs in Canada.

All PCs use the same time zone (UTC-5). The only difference is the country set in "Region and Language/Location"

Can someone explain how is this possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the following article it explains the (not) working of time synchronize:
http://www.pretentiousname.com/timesync/

In short:
The time synchronize job only runs once a week, and because the interal clocks of computers are unreliable you get a time difference..
Solution is to create a special sync Task that runs more often to keep the time up to date.. (al explained in the article)